# Swift rating system loop and assign

Tags: swift, conditional-statements, rating, vapor

Trying to build a rating system in Swift and looking for a cleaner way to loop through each of the values.

```
private func calculateRating(user: String) throws -> String {
    let query = try Rating.makeQuery().filter("user", user).all()
    var fiveStars = [Int]()
    var fourStars = [Int]()
    var threeStars = [Int]()
    var twoStars = [Int]()
    var onestar = [Int]()
    if query.count > 1 {

        for rating in query {
            // Check each value and assign it to its associated value
            // insert large if/else condition here :)
        }
        // Perform calculation and return value below
        return ""
    } else {
        // Only one rating has been set
        return query[0].value
    }
}
```

Currently I'm looping through each of the values and assigning the rating to it's associated array `fiveStars` `fourStars` etc. I will then calculate the rating by the standard multiplication method. Is there a cleaner way to loop through the ratings and assign it to the relevant `fiveStars` array etc without creating a long if/else conditional?

Thanks

Edit: Sample output would be a single rounded up value out of 5 i.e. "4" out of five based on 1000's of multiple ratings.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have just one array of rated things rather than a `fiveStars` array, a `fourStars` array, and so on? It would be useful if you'd show what it is that's being rated so we can advise how to loop through one list of them. In other words, show sample input and desired output; it's unclear what aim you're trying to achieve.

Comment: A one time rating per activity by user. In order to work out the "out of five" rating I need to split each value and multiply the total of each by it's value then divide to give the result. Unless there's a simpler way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let twoStars: [Int]  = query.filter {$0.val == 2} .map {$0.val}
```

And so on.

Comment: This solved my issue with the following changes `let twoStars: [Int] = query.filter({ $0.value == 5 }).map({$0.value})`

Comment: This solves the issue as given, but I still think that dealing out the activities into arrays called `fiveStars`, `foursStars` and so on is just wrong.

Comment: Also I don't think you should be accepting as your answer a line of code that doesn't even compile.

Comment: @matt I've fixed. Btw, you can fix a simple typo by yourself

Comment: @user7684436 you can remove external parenthesis

Comment: Compiled at my end!